# Excel, scan a cell looking for specific charaters and write value from postion 1 to the first "."

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a spreadsheet with over 29,000 lines and i would like to scan Column A than write a value in column K. the data in Column A is as follows:

```
        A
SYS1.AHI4.PAGE.LOCAL4.DATA
NZR5Q8.OPSLOG.RESTORE.DATA
PUSET.AUNBU.D.GSS.V2R8M0.PARMLIB.G1608V00
PPRAD.PAXLB.DRAINFO.G0012V00
PTASS.SIMCH.MSTRJCL
OMVS.VAI4R11.SOS.NETVIEW.ZFS.DATA
WZWV7W.SYS1.TCPPARMS
XZGRH5.SYS1.TCPPARMS
XZ6M8X.SYS3A.IS.LINKLIB.DB2
NZWNGS.ISPF.ISPPROF
NZWNGS.PDS.CLIST
```

i would like to scan Column A looking for the letter 'Z' in position 2, once found look for the first '.' and take the first position upto the '.' and write the value in column K.

to look like this:

```
  K
NZR5Q8
WZMV7W
WZWV7W
XZGRH5
XZ6M8X
NZWNGS
```

Can someone help?.... please send to mark.zaszczurynski@gm.com

Answer (score 1):

Give this a try:

```
Sub KaptureData()
    Dim K As Long, i As Long

    K = 1

    For i = 1 To Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        If Mid(Cells(i, 1).Text, 2, 1) = "Z" Then
            Cells(K, "K").Value = Split(Cells(i, 1).Text, ".")(0)
            K = K + 1
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```

[image]